# Can't save to local table when network access is interrupted.

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a split database where the backend is located remotely; when I get the error "Network access has been interrupted" I want to log something on a local table for future access.  After creating a system for this I found out that when the connection is lost to the remote backend the local tables also become inaccessible.

While I don't think there is necessarily a solution to this I want to find out why the local tables aren’t accessible when clearly they shouldn't require a network connection to be used. The following is the code for my function that I use to try and log locally.

```
Public Function LogTempError(ByVal lngErrNumber As Long, _
                         ByVal strErrDescription As String, _
                         strCallingProc As String, _
                         Optional varParameters As Variant, _
                         Optional blnSHOW_USER As Boolean = True) As Boolean

On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    'Set warnings to True just in case the error happened while they were set to false.
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = DBEngine(0)(0).OpenRecordset("TempErrorTable", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

    With rs
        .AddNew
            !ERROR_LOG_NUMBER = lngErrNumber
            !ERROR_LOG_USERID = NetworkUserName()
            !ERROR_LOG_DESCRIPTION = strErrDescription & " logged from Temp Table"
            !ERROR_LOG_TIMESTAMP = Now()
            !ERROR_LOG_FORM = strCallingProc
        .Update
    End With


Exit_Handler:
On Error Resume Next
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    If DateDiff("s", dteLAST_ERROR_TIME, Now()) > 20 Or lngLAST_ERROR_NUMBER <> lngErrNumber Then

        ' If there are more errors that can't be logged, simply email the errors.
        SendEmail "First Unloggable error", "Error Num: " & Err.Number & " Error Description: " & strErrDescription & " From: " & strCallingProc
        SendEmail "Second Unloggable error", "Error Num: " & Err.Number & " Error Description: " &     Err.Description & " From: " & strCallingProc

        MsgBox "An error occured that wasn't able to be logged, a message was sent to Database Administrator on your behalf.", vbInformation, "Notification Sent"

End If

Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I'm curious how crippled Access becomes in that situation.  Will it allow you to log your error data to a text file?

Comment: That is an interesting idea.  I feel I know the answer simply because I have a timer that runs on the main form every 60 seconds.  However after getting the first round of unloggable errors from the timer, a second round never hits.  That seems to indicate that Access pretty much just fully breaks and needs to be restarted before it can do anything.    The errors that happen after the first error is always Error 0, which if memory serves me correct means that the VBA code can’t run/compile.   I will try to write to text file just for curiosity’s sake though.

Comment: Actually I have to rescind that comment, the emails do get sent out to me so that seems to indicate that access is able to perform some functionality, just none that have to do with connections to the tables.

Comment: After some testing it seems like I can manually access the local tables, but not through VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Try this slightly stripped-down version, which opens the connection to TempErrorTable on first use, and keeps the connection open. Let it stop on errors within LogTempError so you can see where the TempErrorTable update is failing.

```
Public Function LogTempError(ByVal lngErrNumber As Long, _
                     ByVal strErrDescription As String, _
                     strCallingProc As String, _
                     Optional varParameters As Variant, _
                     Optional blnSHOW_USER As Boolean = True) As Boolean
Static rs As Recordset
On Error GoTo 0
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
If rs Is Nothing Then       ' open recordset on first use
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("TempErrorTable", dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)
End If
With rs
  .AddNew
    !ERROR_LOG_NUMBER = lngErrNumber
    !ERROR_LOG_USERID = NetworkUserName()
    !ERROR_LOG_DESCRIPTION = strErrDescription & " logged from Temp Table"
    !ERROR_LOG_TIMESTAMP = Now()
    !ERROR_LOG_FORM = strCallingProc
  .Update
End With
Exit Function
```